Rolling without slipping and tangential accelereation of the contact point
Let's consider a wheel that rolls without slipping on a plane surface. I know that the rolling without slipping condition means that the velocity of the contact point of the wheel relative to the ground must be zero. Therefore, the tangential acceleration of the contact point of the wheel must also be zero. I don' t understand how we deduce this last fact from the first. Or are they equivalent? I'm having a hard time trying to grasp this.

Tangential acceleration of the contact point can be non-zero. Sounds strange but it happens all the time. Imagine a ball thrown into the air at its highest point, with zero velocity but constant non-zero acceleration. So these two facts are not related and should not be considered together.
As to the specific case you mentioned. You can seperate the contact point's movement into its motion relative to the axis' and the axis' translation. Whatever translational acceleration they have must cancel each out.
But a more physical perspective to appraoch it will be imagine the wheel to be of infinite radius,which should not change the nature of the motion in the horizontal direction. Then the contact point on the wheel must stay motionless for a period of time, so the translational acceleration must be 0.

Are you sure? My teacher told us that the contact point only has a normal component of the acceleration. He explained that the acceleration due to the rotational motion and the acceleration due to the translational motion cancel out, leaving only the normal component. But if this is not true it means I´m really lost here haha.

@user420735 sorry I haven't given your problem a proper thought. What I wanted to emphasize is the first paragraph.

Here is a closeup sketch of a point on the wheel as approaches the bottom, makes a soft landing, and lifts off again. You can see that the motion is at least approximately vertical. At the very bottom, the last infinitesimal motion is exactly vertical.
The second sketch shows how the point acquires a horizontal velocity as it rises. At the top, the velocity is entirely horizontal, and is double the speed of the axle.
The average horizontal speed of the point is the same as the axle. The average vertical speed of the point is $0$, again the same as the axle. This is why the average motion of the point is to keep up with the axle.
This might be easier to visualize if you think about tank treads.


Thanks! It's illustrative to see it that way.

Velocity of the contact point is another way to call the relative velocity between the ground and the periphery of the wheel.
If a wheel with angular velocity $\omega$ and radius $R$ is static in relation to the ground, this relative velocity is of course $v_t = \omega R$.
If the wheel moves exactly with this velocity, the relative velocity is $v_{cp} = v_w - v_t = 0$. The acceleration is $$a_{cp} = \frac{dv_{cp}}{dt} = \frac{dv_w}{dt} - \frac{dv_t}{dt}$$ As $v_w = v_t$ by hypothesis, the acceleration is zero.
